Showing that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}e^{\mu h}\int_0^h e^{-\mu t}A(t)xdt = A(0)x$
Let $A(t)\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be a continuous matrix-valued function in $t$ (in matrix operator norm) for $t\geq 0$ such that $\|A(t)\| \leq Ce^{b t}$ for $b \in\mathbb{R}$ and some $C\geq 1$. Suppose that $\mu\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathfrak{Re}(\mu) > b$ and let $x\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$. I am trying to show that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}e^{\mu h}\int_0^h e^{-\mu t}A(t)xdt = A(0)x$$
The integrals can be interpreted in the Bochner integral sense, so that for any matrix $B$ we have
$$B\int_0^h A(t)dt = \int_0^h BA(t)dt$$
provided that
$$\int_0^h||A(t)||dt < \infty$$
(in fact, we have that $\|\int_0^hA(t)dt\|\leq \int_0^h \|A(t)\|dt$ in the matrix norm sense)
So, showing that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}e^{\mu h}\int_0^h e^{-\mu t}dt = 1$$
is relatively straightforward, but now since we can't necessarily compute the integral $\int_0^h e^{-\mu t}A(t)xdt$ for any $h > 0$, we have to show that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\|\frac{1}{h}e^{\mu h}\int_0^h e^{-\mu t}A(t)xdt - A(0)x\| = 0$$
But I am not really sure about the exact details, i.e. how I should represent $A(0)x$. One can start by writing
$$\|\frac{1}{h}e^{\mu h}\int_0^h e^{-\mu t}A(t)xdt - \frac{1}{h}\int_0^hA(0)xdt\|\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\|\frac{1}{h}\int_0^h e^{\mu h}e^{-\mu t}A(t)x - A(0)xdt\|$$
but after moving the norm inside the integral,
$$\|\frac{1}{h}\int_0^h e^{\mu h}e^{-\mu t}A(t)x - A(0)xdt\|\leq \frac{1}{h}\int_0^h\|\left(e^{\mu h}e^{-\mu t}A(t)x - A(0)\right)x\|dt$$
I think that to goal is to find some upper bound $D(s)$ s.t.
1.) $$\forall s\in\left[0, h\right]:  \|\left(e^{\mu h}e^{-\mu t}A(t)x - A(0)\right)x\|\leq D(s)\|x\|$$, as then the integral over $\left[0, h\right]$ will cancel $\frac{1}{h}$;
2.) $$\lim_{s\to 0}D(s) = 0$$
As of writing I know how I should further manipulate the integrand.

If $t\mapsto B(t)$ from $R$ to $R^d$ is continuous, then by dominated convergence
$$\frac{1}{h}\int_0^hB(t)dt=\int_0^1B(hu)du\to_{h\to 0} B(0)$$
